# Filling NA in data.frame with first non NA

Tags: r, replace, na

I'm having particular issues with imputation of NA values in dataframe, as in below examples. I need to replace missing data in the dataframe with the first non missing value in the same row from the right. For example, my data look like this:

```
group <-c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')
year1<- c(NA,'100',NA,'200','300',NA,NA)
year2<- c(NA,'100',NA,'200','300','50','40')
year3<- c('20','100',10,'200','300','150','230')
data=data.frame(group,year1,year2,year3)
```

[image]

But i want it to be like in final data:

```
group <-c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')
year1<- c('20','100','10','200','300','50','40')
year2<- c('20','100','10','200','300','50','40')
year3<- c('20','100',10,'200','300','150','230')
finaldata=data.frame(group,year1,year2,year3)
```

[image]

I understand that there is function `na.locf(somevector, fromLast = TRUE)` that does similar, but i want it on the whole data frame row by row?

Thanks!

Comment: `map2_df(data,list(coalesce(!!!data[-1])),coalesce)` should work

Comment: thanks a lot this is very efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform the data to a long format and then use `na.locf`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  gather(key, value, year1:year3) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(value = zoo::na.locf(value, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   group [7]
  group year1 year2 year3
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     20    20    20   
2 B     100   100   100  
3 C     10    10    10   
4 D     200   200   200  
5 E     300   300   300  
6 F     50    50    150  
7 G     40    40    230
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using (most importantly) `coalesce` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_at(dat, 
          vars(starts_with("year")), 
          funs(replace(., is.na(.), do.call(coalesce, dat[-1])[is.na(.)])))
#  group year1 year2 year3
#1     A    20    20    20
#2     B   100   100   100
#3     C    10    10    10
#4     D   200   200   200
#5     E   300   300   300
#6     F    50    50   150
#7     G    40    40   230
```

The idea here is to `replace` `NA`s for every column that starts with "year" by what is the result of `do.call(coalesce, dat[-1])`, i.e.

```
[1] "20"  "100" "10"  "200" "300" "50"  "40"
```

These are the first non-`NA`s for every row (first column excluded for obvious reasons).

**data**

```
dat <- data.frame(group,year1,year2,year3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```